# how to set background image to control using actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Is it possible to do with application or anyother control except image control

Comment: why the downvotes on this? Seems like a perfectly valid programming question to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`myControl.setStyle('backgroundImage', image);`

Presuming your control inherits from `UIComponent`